# In my web, When I click the Save button more than once, It is saved a lot. Any solutions? As React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
handleSaveExam = (e, errors) => {

      this.setState({
        error: false,
        loading: true
      })
........
onClick{handleSaveExam}
```

The solution to get is that 'when I click save button more than once, It will be saved only one. 
Where would be solution and logical issue. Please share the solutions you have found as soon as possible.

Comment: you can use debounce - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce

Comment: please make sure you format your code and also mention what have you tried. it healthy to maintain a discussion rather than just plain question and answer.

Comment: Debouncing the submit may help from rapid clickers, but it sounds more like you desire the submit to be disabled until some processing has completed. Is this correct?

Comment: There is a way that you handle the button state to disable, until your file saved. Then you could let it just click only once?

Comment: (Set disable to false at the end of saved action)

Comment: Or I would agree with @Rigorousimplementation opinion.